# URL rewriting using php not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have my url as 
http://public_html.com/sub-products.php?catid=42

I want it to look like
http://public_html.com/sub-products/catid/42

I have made a **.htaccess** file too. but still there is no change in my url

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule   ^sub-products/catid/([0-9]+)/?$   sub-products.php?catid=$1 [L]
```

Do i need to change anything in my php file also?

what code is required for php file to use **.htaccess** file?

Comment: nothing. just saved on the same location where project is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Sangram i did it already stil not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a purpose to your line

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

But i can't see it for the need you have, so i guess a

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^sub-products/catid/([0-9]+)/?$ /sub-products.php?catid=$1 [L]
```

should work.

Edit :

This should work if you are trying to access the http://public_html.com/sub-products/catid/42 url

(or http://public_html.com/sub-products/catid/42/ btw)

If what you want is going from

http://public_html.com/sub-products.php?catid=42

to

http://public_html.com/sub-products/catid/42/

You might need something like this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^catid=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^sub-products.php$ /sub-products/catid/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

And then, you can use what i said before.

Comment: Do you even need the `.php` in `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` ? Should it be: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` ?

Comment: Indeed, my mistake, i guess it came with the `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php` line

Comment: yes it is working with %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f. But my concern is that the usl is not being renamed then even. I am still getting the old URL only.  @Big Chris

Comment: Change: `RewriteRule ^sub-products/catid/([0-9]+)/?$ /sub-products.php?catid=$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^sub-products/catid/([0-9]+)/?$ sub-products.php?catid=$1 [L]`

Comment: Since it wasn't working (and it should), i added some instructions, in case there is a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule in .htaccess rewrite only incoming seo-pretty URls to URL with php script filename. But if you need construct url as */sub-products/catid/42* you have to change you PHP code, that render HTML output.

for example

```
while ( $products as $product ) {
  echo '<a href="/sub-products/catid/"'.$product['id'].'>'.$product['name'].'</a>;
}
```

Comment: I am getting the catid from database. so it will be changing every time user select something else. So do i have to still include the same code for my php file? @cendak

Comment: $sqrycat_mst = "select 
 prodcatm_id,prodcatm_name
from   
 vw_prod_all
where
prodcatm_sts ='a' and
prodscatm_sts ='a' and
prodm_sts ='a'
if($cntrec_cat > 0){
while($srowcat_mst=mysql_fetch_assoc($srscat_mst)){
$db_cat_idval  = $srowcat_mst['prodcatm_id'];
if(($db_cat_idval == $db_cat_id) or ($db_cat_idval == $db_lnk_cat_id)  or ($db_cat_idval == $catone_id)){
if($rqst_txtsrchval ==''){
echo "<li class='navactive'>";
}
else{
echo "<li>";
}
     }     
     else{
      echo "<li>";
}
echo "<a href='sub-products?catid=$db_cat_idval'>$srowcat_mst[prodcatm_name]</a></li>";
}
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you switched your first statment around, but it looks in your `.htaccess` file you want to rewrite the other way around. Maybe this would work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} catid=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?sub-products.php /sub-products/catid/%1 [R,L]
```

If you want to have a more generic rule, and not just for `catid` this RewriteRule could work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([a-zA-Z]+)=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?sub-products.php /sub-products/%1/%2 [R,L]
```

Hope it helps you forward.

EDIT: Made some changes after testing it on my system.

Comment: Trying to run on localhost. still not workibg.. Thanks for the suggestion  @Qben

Comment: @Priyanka Updated the answer after testing it on my system. Did some basical mistakes. :)